# SQL - Change value of a column where multiple records contain the same column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on modifying some SQL to enable it to change the value of a column if multiple rows exist with the same value in a particular column.

For example:

```
    id    col1    col2  
    1     114     name1
    2     114     name2
    3     115     name3
```

In the above I would like to be a able to rename the value of col2 in the first and second row as the values of col1 match, so the output would actually be:

```
    id    col1    col2  
    1     114     renamed
    2     114     renamed
    3     115     name3
```

Is there any way to do this within SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update tablename
  set col2 = 'renamed'
where col1 IN (select col1 from tablename
               group by col1
               having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, count distinct which column? If a col1 value occurs twice - regardless of col2 - I set col2 to renamed.

Comment: You could distinct count on the id field.  But I'm not sure what you'd gain.  Remember that distinct counts are more expensive than non-distincts.  Best avoided when not required.

Comment: I can't see why I should involve count distinct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is pretty easy with window functions.  If you want this as an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             min(col2) over (partition by col1) as mincol2,
             max(col2) over (partition by col1) as maxcol2
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set col2 = 'renamed'
    where mincol2 <> maxcol2;
```